# In Excel, how do I find the first instance of a name in an array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel I am trying to identify the first year that a person was a participant.

I have a table that looks like the one below (and attached), but is much longer and has more columns.
As you can see, each year can have multiple events in which someone was a participant.

I have a master list of all names, and I want to line up that list with the year in which the person was first a participant (see attached:

[image: image showing participant master list]

Is there any best way to do this?

Thanks!

```
Year    Participant 1   Participant 2   Participant 3   Participant 4
2010    Ashwin  Day Ayla    Amos
2011    Effie   Aguilar Murtaza Todd
2011    Neive   Amin    Madeleine   Cortez
2012    Ashwin  Cooley  Amin    Quinn
2014    Jak Ashwin  Madeleine   Jaramillo
2015    Amin    Jak Ayla    Madeleine
2016    Madeleine   Aguilar Cortez  Clayton
2016    Lily-Mae    Neive   Larissa Effie
2017    Todd    Day Larissa Cortez
2019    Day Brewer  Cooley  Haney.
```

See attached:

Excel Table showing the Table I am looking at finding the year a participant first participated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Index/Aggregate

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$E$11)/($B$2:$E$11=G2),1))
```

The Aggregate finds the first row in which the name can be found by creating an array of rows where the name is found and errors.  The `15` tells the aggregate to return the lowest number and the `7` tells the formula to ignore the errors.

The row number is then returned to the INDEX and the correct cell value is returned.

[image]